# javascript class members are undefined in child classes

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance

Here is my code, class B inherits class A:

```
function A() {
    this.msg = 'meuahah';
    A.prototype.foo = function() {
        alert(this.msg);
    }
}

function B() {
    A.call(this);
    B.prototype.bar = function() {
        A.prototype.foo();
    }
}

a = new A();
a.foo(); // alerts 'meuahah'
b = new B();
b.bar(); // alerts 'undefined'
```

Why doesn't b.bar() display 'meuahah'?

Comment: Woah... why are we setting stuff to the prototype every time the constructors are called?

Comment: It will work when you try alert(a.msg);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your prototypal inheritance is not quite right. This is probably more what you want to do:

```
function A() {
    this.msg = 'meuahah';
}

A.prototype.foo = function() {
    alert(this.msg);
}

function B() {
    A.call(this);
}

B.prototype = new A();
B.prototype.bar = function() {
    this.foo();
}

a = new A();
a.foo(); 
b = new B();
b.bar();
```

You can override `foo` in `B` like this:

```
B.prototype.foo = function() {
    // Call the original foo method
    A.prototype.foo.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Comment: `B.prototype = A.prototype`.  This is kind of dangerous... after setting `B.prototype.bar`, there is now an `A.prototype.bar` as well, which was likely not the intended behavior.

Comment: Good point I guess I blacked out on that for a moment ;) Should be fixed now.

Comment: That's definitely better, but the problem now is that you'll have a `B.prototype.msg` (and any other properties set in the `A()` constructor.  You would be better off copying each property from `A.prototype` onto `B.prototype`.

Comment: To expand, any behavior in the `A()` constructor is invoked when creating your `B()` constructor's prototype chain, so there's something kind of "wonky" about running constructors prior to any instances actually being created.

Comment: Probably want to be using Object.create rather than either of these options.  See my answer. That preserves the prototype without creating an instance or putting `A`'s local properties on B's prototype chain (not harmful in this case but could be if you weren't copying them all anyway)

Answer (score 2):

Because `this` is bound to the global object in that case.

You're calling this function

```
function() {
        alert(this.msg);
    }
```

when it is not bound to an object.  So `this` will refer to the global object (which is `window` in the browser) and since that won't have a `msg` property, it will alert undefined.

When you call `a = new A()` you create a new object, add msg as a property, and set foo() on its prototype chain.  So when you call `a.foo()` foo is bound to `a` and `this` refers to `a`.

In general you probably want something that looks more like this.

```
function A() {
    this.msg = 'meuahah';
}

A.prototype.foo = function() {
    alert(this.msg);
}

function B() {
    A.call(this);
}

B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);

B.prototype.bar = function() {
    this.foo();
}
```

You can read more about how `this` works in javascript from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword?lq=1)

Answer (score 2):

The reason because `b.bar` displays `undefined` is because the `this` of the `foo` method is `prototype`, and `prototype` doesn't have a `msg` property.

You basically missed the main point, the inheritance. So, here the code revisited:

```
function A() {
  this.msg = 'meuahah';
}

A.prototype.foo = function() {
  alert(this.msg);
}

function B() {
    A.call(this);
}

// Set the inheritance! Or better, the prototype's chain,
// so that any instance of B will have methods of A too
B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);

B.prototype.bar = function() {
  // Because the inheritance, now B has the A's `foo` method too
  this.foo();
}

// But... We can also override it.
B.prototype.foo = function() {
  // do something
  alert("override");
  // then call the original one
  A.prototype.foo.call(this);
}
```

Hope it helps to have a better idea about the objects and constructors. I will suggest to investigate on [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) too, that it's really helpful; and the ES5 methods in general.

The reading [Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) it's also a good start, even if it's a bit old.

Answer (score 0):

You're just called the A.prototype.foo function, so `msg` doesn't exist. Here is the output from the console when you `console.log(this)` inside `A.prototype.foo`

```
A {msg: "meuahah", foo: function}
A {foo: function}
```

The second one is when you call it from inside `B`, as you can see `msg` isn't present.